# How to create Relational Table in sql database(wamp)

Tags: sql

I have two tables named student_table(student_id,student_name),teacher_table(teacher_id,teacher_name). Now I want to create a relational table named teacher_student_table which column will be (id,student_id,teacher_id).
In student_table field named student_id is auto increment and in teacher_table field named teacher_id is auto increment.

And in teacher_student_table field named id is also auto_increment.Now how I can make this type of relational table? need help. I don't know how to create this in sql(wamp localhost)

Comment: Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 2):

You also want to have foreign-keys to the other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE teacher_student_table
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_id int NOT NULL,
teacher_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student_table(student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher_table(teacher_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic SQL and you should easily have been able to look it up in your course litterature.

```
CREATE TABLE teacher_student_table
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_id int NOT NULL,
teacher_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student_table(student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher_table(teacher_id)
)
```